# Python log time window

Tags: python, logging, time

I was asked to edit a script that would allow you time print out a time window of information from a log file.  I am having a hard time figuring out what would be the best way of going about this.  The logs have the time at the start of the log as follows:

```
[11-Oct-2012 07:41:22.205608
```

I would need to be able to narrow it down by hour, min, or  seconds.  I don't care about the day month or year.

Comment: i take it records are guaranteed to be in chronological order?

Comment: So, to clarify: are you trying to take a log file and print out only those records from the file with timestamps in a given range?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime("11-Oct-2012 07:41:22.205608", "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

would be the way to do it.

> http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime -
>   return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format...